# Make int overload a preferable one

Tags: c++

Consider following code snippet:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void bar(std::size_t){}
    void bar(const char* ){}
};

int main() {
    auto foo = Foo{};
    foo.bar(0);
}
```

It produces ambiguous calls errors (check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rjGox6rW3)). But I think from programmer's perspective it is pretty obvious that I want to call overload with `std::size_t`. My question is if anything can be done so this code does not produce errors and calls `size_t` overload?

Comment: We may consider switching from `const char*` to `std::string_view`

Comment: Make the first one a template, and use SFINAE or `requires` to restrict template parameter to integers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, that's something I have forgotten about. If you throw it as a answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can be done like this in C++ 20

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
class Foo {
public:
    template <typename T>
    requires std::is_integral_v<T>
    void bar(T){
        std::cout<<"hello size_T";
    }
    
    
    void bar(const char* ){
        std::cout<<"hello";
    }
};

int main() {
    auto foo = Foo{};
    foo.bar(25);
}
```

Comment: This is cleaner https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7MWG5er54

Answer (score 1):

In modern c++ (at least c++17), we prefer to pass `string_view` as argument over `const char*` for the none owner transfer cases, so a considerable choice:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
class Foo {
public:
    void bar(std::size_t){}
    void bar(std::string_view){}
};

int main() {
    auto foo = Foo{};
    foo.bar(0);
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ocxfhxxK3)

Answer (score 0):

In below C++ 20, this works well.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    template <typename T>   
    void bar(T) {
        std::cout << "hello T" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar(const char* c) {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto foo = Foo{};
    foo.bar(0);
    foo.bar("test.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in C++23:

```
foo.bar(0zu);
```

and this works pre-C++23:

```
foo.bar(size_t{0});
```